# Container does not have access to serial port over reboots despite privileged and device

Tags: docker, reboot

Host - Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry pi 4

Container - arm64v8/ros:noetic-ros-core

I'm using docker compose to bring my container up. When launched from the CLI, everything works fine. However, when i reboot, the container no longer has access to the serial port. I.e /dev/ttyACM0 is available on the host but not on the container.

Privileged is set to true, and iv'e also added the device specifically (although this was not required when launching it from the CLI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.2"

services:

ugv:
  image: ugv:latest
  restart: always
  tty: true
  stdin_open: true
  privileged: true
  devices:
    - "/dev/ttyACM0:/dev/ttyACM0"

  command: /bin/bash -c "source devel/setup.bash && roslaunch ugv2 ugv_bringup.launch"
  network_mode: host
  environment:
    - ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.150:11311
    - ROS_IP=192.168.1.150
  logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
      max-file: "2"
      max-size: 10m
```

Comment: adding /dev as a volume seems to fix it, although it's a bit bizare that you need to do this - 
    volumes:
      - "/dev:/dev"